# Split Test CALCULATOR for asp.net?

Tags: c#

I have a/b test (split test) running on asp.net. It shows variations, visitors and conversions. If I punch these numbers in any split test calculator, it will show me Confidence Level and if there is a winner. Wonder maybe there is a library which calculates it, so I could show these calc results on my page? or formula which I could implement myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the source of [FairlyCertain](http://www.fairtutor.com/fairlycertain/).  It's an A/B Testing library in C#, and it has utility classes that handle the statistics calculations you'll want to do.

It's pretty modular, so hopefully you'll be able to tear out a single class and drop it into your project.